# What is this JavaScript syntax: {Ci, CC}?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm doing some FF add-on development and I'm seeing syntax like this:

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
```

Just curious what that syntax is and if it's special to FF development or something else.

Comment: How can I prevent it to be appear like error in Visual Studio + Resharper? Since it is not recognized as natural syntax of javascript, ReSharper keeps showing it as an syntax error and cannot reformat document.

Comment: How did this *earlier* question get marked as a dupe of the same thing asked in 2013?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See Domenic's answer as to what the syntax is which is called a destructuring assignment. The answer that follows is why this is needed for FF add-on development.

There's a discussion on what this is and why it is needed at http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack/browse_thread/thread/d288b79903b5b434.

Short answer is yes, it's specific for Firefox add-on development.  The relevant documentation can be found at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html.

Comment: Wrong answer. It’s ECMA 6 syntax, and just because Firefox is the first browser implementing destructuring assignments doesn’t mean it’s only relevant for FIrefox addon development.

Comment: I think I answered the wrong question - I thought they were asking why you now need to `require('chrome')` for FF add-ons.  Unfortunately the answer was accepted and so I cannot delete it.

Comment: Ah, got it! I thought it was pretty obvious that the `{...} =` syntax is the weird thing here, as `require('...')` is a simple function call. But the question isn’t unambiguous, you’re right!

Answer (score 35):

This is called destructuring assignment. It is a feature of [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29), where in this context "JavaScript" refers to Mozilla's specific extensions to the ECMAScript standard.

It is slated for [inclusion in the next version of JavaScript](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring).

The equivalent ECMAScript 5 code would be

```
var __temp = require('chrome');
var Cc = __temp.Cc;
var Ci = __temp.Ci;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, i finally got rid of the syntax error in my editor and my code is being evaluated again.

Comment: But does it actually cause a variable `__temp` to come into existence? If not then the equivalence is only a rough one.