# What is `var { comma, separated, list } = name;` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the [react-native getting started example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), there is this code:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;
```

What is the `var {...} = thing;` saying?

Comment: also possible duplicate of [What is this JavaScript syntax: `{Ci, CC} = `?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9271570/1048572)